# What does `moshi` in the adapter-constructor generated by codegen mean?

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm a newbee in kotlin-android development.

I want to parse a JSON like

```
{
  "name": "This is my name",
}
```

to a `Foo` class defined as

Foo.kt

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Foo(val name: String)
```

This `Foo` class file generates a code by codegen as follows.

FooJsonAdapter.kt (generated by codegen)

```
class FooJsonAdapter(moshi: Moshi) : JsonAdapter<Foo>() {
    private val options: JsonReader.Options

    private val stringAdapter: JsonAdapter<String>

    override fun toString(): String

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Foo 

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Foo?) 
}
```

The `FooJsonAdapter` class's constructor specifies `Moshi` object, and here is my question.
What kind of `Moshi` object should be passed to the constructor? I tried the following, but this does not work.

MainActivity.kt

```
Moshi.Builder().add(
    FooJsonAdapter(
        Moshi.Builder().build()
    )
).build()
```

Error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hoge, PID: 31816
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hoge/com.example.hoge.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected at least one @ToJson or @FromJson method on com.example.hoge.FooJsonAdapter
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected at least one @ToJson or @FromJson method on com.example.hoge.FooJsonAdapter
        at com.squareup.moshi.AdapterMethodsFactory.get(AdapterMethodsFactory.java:137)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi$Builder.add(Moshi.java:237)
        at com.example.hoge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

What should I do? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`Moshi.Builder.add(Type, JsonAdapter)`](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/687acba7602a9ca87b5ac0324ce39088f07139a8/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/Moshi.java#L193) instead of [`Moshi.Builder.add(JsonAdapter)`](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/687acba7602a9ca87b5ac0324ce39088f07139a8/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/Moshi.java#L236)

Comment: Also! Don't use the generated code directly. Instead ask your Moshi instance to do that for you.

Comment: @JesseWilson I don't know how to do that... (1) I create a Moshi instance by `Moshi.Builder().build()`, and then what should I do for the Moshi instance?

Comment: Use it to look up the adapter.

Comment: @JesseWilson would you mind either pointing me to some documentation or briefly going into why we shouldn't directly call the constructor on generated adapters? I am seeing a very strange error and I'm thinking it could be related to this.

Comment: The generated code is not intended as a public API and may break between releases.